On choice of y-axis range for visualization
Let's say that a disease has low prevalence. The prevalence is the proportion which should range from 0% to 100%. I want to visualize the trend of prevalence over the time. (Let's assume that visualizing prevalence is the only correct way for simplicity.)
Let's say prevalence at t=1,2 and 3 are 1%,1.5% and 1.75%, respectively. And we also assume the CIs associated with prevalence are sort of wide.
Option 1: I could plot the graph prevalence over time with y-axis range from 0 to 2% to show increasing trend.
Option 2: I could plot the graph prevalence over time with y-axis range from 0 to 10% to show slight increasing trend.
Option 3: I could plot the graph prevalence over time with y-axis range from 0 to 100% to show almost no increasing trend.
$Q:$ Is there a guideline on choice of range of y-axis for visualization? If the prevalence is high enough, I would use y-axis with range 0 to 100%.
$Q:$ From testing results of a trend test, which graph should I report ethically? (There are 4 scenarios, significant and clinical relevant, non-significant and clinical relevant, insignificant and clinically irrelevant, insignificant and clinically irrelevant.)  It seems that whatever I do is doing propaganda generation here. With small population size, I could see that option 2 might be reasonable. With large population, option 1 might be reasonable to indicate that more people suffer from the disease over the time.

When clinical journals publish survival curves, it is common to plot the graph two ways. One with %death (or % survival) going from 0 to 100, and the other focussing just on just the range that includes the data (and the confidence intervals) That second graph is usually inset on the first one.

@HarveyMotulsky Well for CIF and survival probabilities, it is a slightly different story. However, I could still imagine that a propaganda is drawn on a that graph as well by cutting off the y-axis at a particular upper or lower threshold depending upon CIF or survival probability.

A y-axis range that is just large enough to show the entire range of the confidence intervals over time would be most useful for your audience.
With properly labeled axes there is no "propaganda" involved; you are providing a summary plot that shows the critical information from your study without a lot of wasted white space. It represents the fundamental data on which a statistical test for trend would be based, at the largest visual scale that encompasses the data summary.
The statistical test for trend will stand on its own regardless of how the data summary is displayed. The suggested plot will be useful whether the statistical test (combined with your understanding of the subject matter) indicates the trend is "significant and clinically relevant, non-significant and clinically relevant, insignificant and clinically irrelevant, insignificant and clinically irrelevant."

First recommendation is to include 0, which is what your 3 proposals do.
Second one is to absolutely show the CI's on your plot; not showing the CI's is hiding the uncertainty on your prevalence estimates. And showing the CI's indirectly deals with the sample size (sizes if they are not the same at each time point). Particularly as you say that the CI's are "sort of  wide".
The issue now is that with your options 1 or 2, you will emphasize the fact that the prevalence grew by 75% (big change!). But your option 3 shows that the prevalence grew by 0.75 percentage points (small change!).
So do your significance test, and use your domain expertise to arrive at one of the 4 possible conclusions:significant and clinical relevant, non-significant and clinical relevant, significant and clinically non-relevant, non-significant and clinically non-relevant". And pick the graph(s?) which best show the actual conclusion of your analysis; this is not propaganda, but actually showing the actual situation in a convincing way.
So if e.g. you have significant and clinically relevant, use a small y scale (e.g. Option 2 or so). But if non-significant and non-relevant, use Option 2 or even 3.
My basic point is that if your graph is congruent with the conclusion of your analysis, you are not engaging in "propaganda".
However, note that it also depends on the readability of your graph. Option 3 may (?) make the CI's visually so small that it can not really be interpreted. So pick a $Y_{max}$ value small enough to make it readable/interpretable.
